# facebook->getLoginUrl do not prompt login

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Im developing a mobile login with facebook. However, the getLoginUrl do not prompt for facebook login when i've logout facebook from my device (mobile safari and facebook Apps). Instead of prompt for facebook login, it show me error message **"Not logged in. You are not logged in, please login and try again".**

here is my code. it pretty simple and easy.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                                       'appId'      => $app_id,
                                       'secret' => $app_secret,
                                       ));
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                                                 'scope'            => 'email,publish_stream,publish_actions,user_games_activity,friends_games_activity,user_likes',
                                                 'redirect_uri' => 'http://m.xxx.local/login.php'
                                                 ));
```

and this is the return : [login url](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=284177318323946&redirect_uri=http://m.csysports.local/login.php&state=2ce168f3af4813242b2683343d39f1b0&scope=email,publish_stream,publish_actions,user_games_activity,friends_games_activity,user_likes=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=284177318323946&redirect_uri=http://m.csysports.local/login.php&state=2ce168f3af4813242b2683343d39f1b0&scope=email,publish_stream,publish_actions,user_games_activity,friends_games_activity,user_likes)

i've tested this url, it work on desktop safari, but when i change the user agent into mobile in safari, it failed to prompt me.

Any idea? im stucked.

PS: when i got valid login in mobile safari, this like is working perfectly.